# Cyanogenmod without google apps

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-maps

I flashed my Android with Cyanogenmod 11 without google apps, the sole intention being to avoid Google whatsoever. I am using Runtastic to log my runs, but it doesn't display the map. Understandbly, because Google maps app is not installed. My question is if I can install some other maps like bing maps etc. and use it with Runtastic.

PS: I have no intention to install Google maps or any other google product on my phone.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why? I understand not wanting to give Google all your date (that's fair enough) but you are still giving all that data to Runtastic and any other location based app (giving it to Microsoft via Bing) you may use... Are they any more trust worthy really?

Comment: I'm sure Google is more evil than the rest :) Otherwise why would they retain Google location history and why does they need my wifi details and passwords.

Comment: Yeah I get you! I do actually use location history for Google Now to see if there's any traffic alerts or issues, and I backup my passwords and contacts to Google. That said, I do understand why you might not want to, I just wouldn't be too confident in Microsoft or random 3rd party app developers at all either.

Answer (score 4):

You might wish to take a look at the **[NOGAPPS project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375)**, which is what I am using. Without having to install the GApps, it e.g. provides a MapsAPI in a way that other apps think it's GMaps. There's also a NetworkLocation provider able to use a locally stored CellID database – found my location on the spot. Third part is the BlankStore, allowing access to the PlayStore including License-verification for paid apps (you cannot buy apps with this, but you can use apps you've already bought). Perfect trio.

You might also wish to see my article on this topic: [Android without Google 6: Self-Experiment](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-6) (need to update it with my progress on another device, where all 3 components work fine).

Comment: Waiting for your update on that article. Like to see what findings you ended up with.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN that will take a little, as I'm just leaving for vacation. Basically, on my Motorola Milestone the entire NOGAPPS package seems to work fine: BlankStore, NetworkLocation, Maps. My paid apps work, I even could install them via BlankStore.

Comment: glad to hear it's going good, smoothly i should say. Enjoy your vacation, be safe.

Comment: @Izzy, Can you help me troubleshoot NOGAPPS. I followed the instructions and flashed the NoGapps, but still "Runtastic" app fails to display map. It says Google Play Services required. Can you help?

Comment: Afraid not. Maps display fine with the apps I use, but if some other parts of the *Play Services* are required by an app, that might be different. NOGAPPS AFAIK only support v1 of the Maps-API currently, it might be that Runtastic explicitly requires v2.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Stop waiting, go reading. Then maybe wait again for the next update ;) In short: Not much missing, basically only *Google Cloud Messaging* for notifications in the SE app ;)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN article finished last week :)

Comment: @Izzy going to read that this afternoon, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

[OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) uses the collaboratively-edited OpenStreetMaps database, and **doesn't need to send your information anywhere** since you can choose to download the maps locally to your phone.

They don't make it clear on their website, but there is a [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) build, [“OsmAnd~”, available from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus).

More generally, using CyanogenMod free from Google is discussed in some detail in the 2014-06-18 LWN article “[Android without the mother ship](http://lwn.net/Articles/602521/)”.